# Rational Approximation Theorem

Tags: continued-fractions, diophantine-approximation

I noticed this theorem mentioned in a book and I couldn't seem to find what it is called and/or see a proof of it. The closest I could find is the Drichlet Approximation Theorem.

The theorem in question is:

If $\vert{x - r/s}\vert < 1/2s^2$ for integers $r, s$ then ${r \over s} = {p_i \over q_i}$ for some $i$, where $p_i \over q_i$  is a finite termination at step $i$ of the continued fraction of $x$. In other words

$$
{p_i \over q_i} = a_0 + \frac{1}{a_1 + \frac{1}{... + \frac{1}{a_i}}}
$$

Could somebody point me to a proof of this theorem and or tell me how I could start proving it?

A paper stated this as a "classic approximation relation" if that helps.

Comment: This is used to prove irrationality and to determine the best possible rational approximation of a number given a specific degree numerator and denominator.

Comment: In fact, you can strengthen the RHS to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}s^2}$. Look up Hutwitz's Theorem.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Do you have a reference to a nice simple proof of it?

Comment: a simple proof? No. I can lead you to proofs of it though. I enjoy the proof given in the book "A Mathematical Omnibus" compiled by Fuchs and Tabachnikov and published by the AMS.

Comment: it's not a simple thing to prove at all. A similar result, proven in 1958 by Klaus Roth, allows us to prove a number is irrational and earned him the Fields Medal, arguably the most prestigious award in mathematics... Though I would expect any grad student to be able to follow a proof of Hutwitz's Theorem with enough work. I first read through the proof in the Mathematical Omnibus at the age of 15 with only a few calculus classes and extremely elementary linear algebra under my belt, and I was able to understand a great deal of the proof

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen What an excellent reference in general; the proof seems really interesting and I'll definitely look through it. Thank you! My question is now reduced to, given that we assume Hurwitz's Theorem, how can you prove the exact statement in my question. It shouldn't be incredibly hard but I can't seem to make the connection immediately.

Comment: Hurwitz's Theorem states there are infinitely many fractions $r \over s$ s.t. $\vert a - \frac{r}{s}  \vert < {1\over \sqrt{5}s^2}$. My question is proving that $r \over s$ is one of the convergence of $x$.

Comment: you're right. There is a key difference.... The important thing here is that the two are intrinsically related! I again point you to the Mathematical Omnibus... The proof is actually focused on showing how to calculate the best rational approximation of a number and proves Hutwitz's Theorem and you're result along the way. It's why I recommended the book.... It shows the connection very well in my opinion (also connects in the Euclidean Algorithm!)

Comment: if you can find a PDF or the like online that would be fantastic... As far as I know the Omnibus simply collects many results from the AMS over time and puts them together, so you might very well be able to find the proofs I mention online even if you can't get a copy of the book. I would try to draw out a proof for you but I unfortunately must sleep now and I'll be busy with a friend's funeral much of the week :/

Comment: That is quite alright, I found a version online. Thank you for all the help! Also my condolences.

Comment: It's probably in the books by Hardy and Wright, and by Niven, Zuckerman, and Montgomery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 19 of Khinchin's book, *Continued Fractions*.